# beforeunload event during window close Vs meteor-auto-reload

Tags: javascript, meteor

I use the follow function to detect window close event to perform some cleanup tasks:

```
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
          console.log("window close");
          // perform cleanup
    }
```

Unfortunately I also get this event during meteor auto-reload (for ex. when there is change in code) during which I don't want to perform cleanup.

How do I differentiate between the two situations? (I have a peculiar usecase where I have to differentiate between the two situations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to tap into the Meteor `onmigrate` api which could help you distuinguish the two:

Client side code:

```
var hotcodepush = false;

Reload._onMigrate(function () {
    hotcodepush = true;
    return [true];
});


window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
      if(!hotcodepush) console.log("window close");
      if(hotcodepush) console.log("Hot code reload");
}
```

Comment: Reload._onMigrate is not available. But Meteor._reload.onMigrate() is available. Maybe something changed recently?

Comment: Yup I think thats the one. All the stuff beginning with underscores is subject to name change

Answer (score -1):

Without knowing meteor. I would try to find the point which is executed just before the auto-update (if possible) and define a abort event|variable|...  I hope this helps