# windows.onBeforeUnload not working with Meteor client side js

Tags: html, meteor, onbeforeunload

I am trying to use windows.onBeforeUnload to flag a boolean in the clientside of my meteor app but it is not working.Can anyone tell me why?

clientside js

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {console.log("I am here");
unloadCheck = true;
};
```

Comment: This almost certainly has nothing to do with Meteor. onbeforeunload is just not very reliable. Some (most?) browsers do not allow you to execute any code, and only consider the return value of that function (which you don't have).

Comment: Thanks . I got it fixed. I have used iron  router routings for the purpose of my functionality. However I am still not sure , how I can understand a window refresh in meteor. Meteor status online observe goes in removed for window refresh which is very scary .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [beforeunload event during window close Vs meteor-auto-reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940888/beforeunload-event-during-window-close-vs-meteor-auto-reload)

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one onbeforeunload handler.

Consider the following sequence:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {console.log("I am here"); };
...
// and in galaxy far far away some meteor will do this:
window.onbeforeunload = function() {console.log("I am there"); };
```

Latter one will override former one so you will have only "I am there".